# Java error: Found interface ... but class was expected

Tags: java, guice

I am getting a strange runtime error from my code:

```
"Found interface [SomeInterface] but class was expected"
```

How can this happen? How can an interface get instantiated?

**Update:** (In response to some answers) I am compiling and running against the same set of libraries, but I **am** using [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) to inject a Provider for this particular Interface.

The problem went away when I bound an implementation to the interface (seems like the @ImplementedBy annotation was not enough).

I was more interested in the mechanics through which Guice managed to actually instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This happens when your runtime classpath is different than your compile time classpath.

When your application was compiled, a class (named `SomeInterface` in your question) existed as a class.

When your application is running at compile time, `SomeInterface` exists as an interface (instead of a class.)

This causes an `IncompatibleClassChangeError` to be thrown at runtime.

This is a common occurence if you had a different version of a jar file on the compile time classpath than on the runtime classpath.

Comment: The stack trace was purely in my own code (and would therefore be useless to anyone else). This is what I found weird. It almost looked like Guice was succeeding in creating an instance of an Interface.

Comment: I have the same issue. It happened when I tried to install joodo (a Clojure framework) and now `lein` commands won't work. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Same weirdness can occur with Mockito when mocking the interface. I discovered today...

Comment: Nice. I encountered this in a Maven project when I changed an interface to an abstract class. So just do `mvn clean` first.

Comment: It can happen in multi module projects as well. Doing a full rebuild of the project can help to solve it.

Comment: A plausible situation is when you update one jar from your dependency list, but you do not update its dependencies. Therefore, if the main new jar was compiled with a newer version of its dependency jars, then this error may occur.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely the code was compiled against a class in a library, which was then changed to an interface in the version you run against.

Comment: ... a simple one-time full rebuild of the project does the job then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I use two jar libraries in my application. One library is built upon the other.

The library A defines top classes and interfaces. Library B requires library A.

This is pseudocode of some code used in library B:

```
TheInterface instance = new TheClass();
instance.someMethod();
```

Apparently library A is newer than library B and `TheInterface` doesn't contain `someMethod` anymore, but `TheClass` still does. The only way to fix this is to get the source for either jar and change these things by hand (if at all possible).

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when i was running a `maven build`.

From what i could gather (as well as from Jared's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/591432/8919607)) as the reason was that - there were two versions of the same 3rd party jar specified in my effective `pom.xml`. One version was coming in as a [transitive dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) and the other was specified by me in my local `pom.xml`.

So at compile time, it was referring to the old version and at runtime it was referring to the new version.

I removed the version specified in my local `pom.xml` and it worked.

Of course, the 3rd party had broken backward-compatibility between their versions and changed a class to an interface or vice-versa. But they are free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you did

```
class MyClass extends SomeInterface
```

when it should actually be

```
class MyClass implements SomeInterface
```

Am I right?

EDIT: Oh, you say it's a *runtime* error and not a *compile-time* error? Let me look around a bit...

EDIT 2: It looks like Jared has the correct answer. Anyway, trying to extend an interface would actually give a "*no interface expected here*" message at compile time, not a "*found interface but class was expected*" error.

Comment: well maybe the code was compiled against a class, but the .class present is another version which has become an interface

Comment: @chburd: Yes, it looks like I was close but didn't quite get it. :)