# Jasper Report error running JUnit

Tags: java, junit, report

Running a JUnit Test (java 7, eclipse EE Juno r1) trying to generate a Jasper Report pdf file I've got the following error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.genConstructor(CallSiteGenerator.java:141)
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Possibly better: [Java error: Found interface … but class was expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591411/java-error-found-interface-but-class-was-expected).

Answer (score 0):

You might have conflicting versions of asm in classpath.

Check out https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rest-assured/YxMorAUsM0A/MfaFvolMSzAJ